# Indexing a JAR using maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: java, maven, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

I'm trying to build a bundle that has an index (`META-INF/INDEX.LIST`) using `maven-bundle-plugin` 2.3.7.

My plugin configuration looks like this

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <index>true</index>
      </archive>
      <instructions>
        <!-- other things like Import-Package -->
        <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

but `META-INF/INDEX.LIST` will not show up in the JAR. I tried to use

```
  <Include-Resource>{maven-resources},META-INF/INDEX.LIST</Include-Resource>
```

but that will fail with

```
[ERROR] Bundle com.acme:project::bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT : Input file does not exist: META-INF/INDEX.LIST
[ERROR] Error(s) found in bundle configuration
```

which is not surprising because `META-INF/INDEX.LIST` is not in `target/classes` but dynamically generated by the Maven Archiver.

**Edit 1**

When I use `jar` instead of `bundle` packaging then the index is there.

**Edit 2**

I'm using Maven 3.0.4

Comment: There is no `target/maven-archiver` folder, only `target/classes`, `target/test-classes`, `target/generated-sources`, `target/generated-test-sources` and `target/surefire-reports`.

Comment: I'm using maven 3.0.4 and the command "mvn org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:bundle" and it does show a maven-archiver in the target. But even I'm not able to generate a INDEX.LIST file. Will update here if I get a solution.

Comment: Why not using mvn clean package ?

Comment: I'm using `mvn clean package` but the resulting jar has no index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dug around in the [maven-bundle-plugin source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.felix/maven-bundle-plugin/2.3.7/org/apache/felix/bundleplugin/BundlePlugin.java?av=f#685), and it looks like the current version (2.3.7) *ignores* the `index` attribute of the archive configuration.  It also ignores `compress`, `forced`, and `pomPropertiesFile`.  The only attributes of the archive configuration it does pay attention to are `addMavenDescriptor`, `manifest`, `manifestEntries`, `manifestFile`, and `manifestSections`.

I'm not sure if there is any other way to manipulate the created archive using only maven-bundle-plugin.

As a possible workaround, you might be able to use the maven-jar-plugin to re-jar the bundle after it's created, telling the jar plugin to create an index, but use the manifest created by the bundle plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <!-- unpack bundle to target/classes -->
        <!-- (true is the default, but setting it explicitly for clarity) -->
        <unpackBundle>true</unpackBundle>
        <instructions>
            <!-- ... your other instructions ... -->
            <Include-Resource>{maven-resources}</Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- List this after maven-bundle-plugin so it gets executed second in the package phase -->
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- overwrite jar created by bundle plugin -->
                <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
                <archive>
                    <!-- use the manifest file created by the bundle plugin -->
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    <!-- bundle plugin already generated the maven descriptor -->
                    <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    <!-- generate index -->
                    <index>true</index>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I'm not too familiar with what's required in a bundle archive, so you might want to double check that everything is correct.